# Xunit Not Running Some Tests in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit, visual-studio-2019, xunit2

Xunit2 is not running some tests properly from within Visual Studio 2019.

I recently migrated from NUnit to Xunit2 (removing all references to it in my projects). I installed Xunit2 following the directions on the official page, along with the nuget test adapter (and I don't have the Visual Studio test extension installed that they recommended not using).

I build my project and the tests are discovered as expected. But only some of them pass or fail, the rest display blue exclamation points (event some in the same class will work, while the rest wont run).

Upon looking at the output, I see the following for the tests not running correctly:

```
...
[7/15/2019 4:04:40 AM Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings. projectxx.dll is built for Framework 4.7.2 and Platform AnyCPU.
[7/15/2019 4:04:42 AM Warning] No test matches the given testcase filter [...]
...
```

So, Visual Studio discovers them all, but Xunit can't find some of them.

All projects are .NET Framework 4.7.2/AnyCPU

Comment: Can you include a (short) re-create?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a single library that just doesn't want to run tests - worked until yesterday...